# Trying to create a jQuery UI modal dialog without a close option

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a modal dialog that appears over a page that shouldn't be accessed but should still be seen from outside of the modal dialog. I have everything working perfectly except for two problems:

- As soon as the modal dialog appears, the link within it is automatically focused, so there is a blue box around it (just like with any element onto which I am focused), but I don't want this behavior.
- Also, there is an X button to allow the user to close the dialog, and I want to get rid of it.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent a jQuery UI dialog from ever being closed:

1. set the option `closeOnEscape` to `false`:

   `$(dlg).dialog('option', 'closeOnEscape', false);`
2. remove its close button just after creation:

   `$(dlg).parent().find('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();`
3. register a NOOP `beforeclose` handler:

   `$(dlg).bind('dialogbeforeclose', false);`

`#1` and `#3` can also be done during creation, of course.

Answer (score 0):

for the 2nd point, try this:

1- Navigate through your jQuery-UI CSS file and find this class

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close
```

2- Modify this class so the Close button will not show, just replace it with the following:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close { disply:none; position: absolute; right: .3em; top: 50%; width: 19px; margin: -10px 0 0 0; padding: 1px; height: 18px; }
```

I just added a new property (Display:none) to make sure the button is not visible to the end user.

let me know if this helped, thanks.

Comment: It's best not to modify the jQuery supplied CSS, but to override it somwhere else.  That way when you upgrade jQuery UI you don't have to patch your CSS over again.  Better yet, remove the `.ui-dialog-titlebar-close` element from the DOM altogether immediately after the dialog is created.