# Dialog pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make register button, but when people click on it. A pop up dialog will appear and has two button for user to click. One is YES , One is NO. IF they select YES, will pass them to X page. Convert way, they select NO, will pass them to Y page. I search on google but only OK and cancel confirm. [image]

YES --> VIP REGISTER

NO --> REGULAR REGISTER

Should i use Jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in classic javascript

```
var answer = confirm ("Do you have vip code?")
```

and then treat the answer accordingly

Comment: it may well be enough, but it is not what was asked for.

Comment: What was asked : "Should i use Jquery?". I am offering a workaround... He should not use jquery ui just for a dialog box; 
sometimes "enough" is all that you are looking for.

Comment: the OP already  specifically said that all he could find was "OK and cancel" i.e. `confirm()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) for this.

```
$('<div>', {text: 'Do you have VIP code?'}).dialog({
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        'Yes': function() {
             window.location = ...;
        },
        'No': function() {
             window.location = ...;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that this dialog box will by default include a "close" button and will also close automatically if you press escape.  You need to either disable those features (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5438771/6782) for how), or decide what action to take (if any) when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `confirm` method if you don't want to customise the look-and-feel of the dialog (you can't change anything, including the text of the buttons):

```
if (confirm("Do you have VIP code?")) {
    //Yes!
} else {
   //No
}
```

If you want to customise the dialog, look at the endless [lightbox scripts](https://www.google.com/search?&q=javascript+lightbox) that are available. As mentioned by @Alnitak, jQuery UI provides a good one.

Answer (score 0):

jquery is a good way to do this very easy. But often the problem is, people belive they can use jQuery without understanding Javascript itself. So, first learn the basics of Javascript (for Example: Methodchaning, Closurs, Array-Handling, Prototyping) and after that try jQuery. The Box you want is very easy to do with [jQuery-UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) and

```
window.location = "vip.html";
```